# How to clone an Option<Rc<_>> in Rust?

Tags: rust, clone

Say I have an `Option` of `Rc`:

```
let x = Some(Rc::new(3));
```

If I need to make a clone, I can do:

```
let y = Some(Rc::clone(&x.unwrap()));
```

But it seems there's also a short cut:

```
let y = x.clone();
```

Are there any difference between these options? Or they are internally doing the same thing?

Comment: Second one is much safer, first one may cause panic due to `unwrap()`, but yes if you think on happy path they do the same

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a [generic implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.44.0/src/libcore/option.rs#L1275-L1283)

```
impl<T: Clone> Clone for Option<T> {
    #[inline]
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        match self {
            Some(x) => Some(x.clone()),
            None => None,
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

So if `x` is `Option<Rc<T>>`, `x.clone()` will simply defer to the `Clone` implementation on `Rc<T>`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. This makes sense. A following up question would be: is `x.clone()` equivalent to `Rc::clone(&x)` in this context?

Comment: @Psidom It should be. `Rc::clone(&x)` is just the `Clone` implementation on `Rc<T>` (applied to a temporary reference - which is what `x.clone()` does too).

Comment: [The book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-04-rc.html#using-rct-to-share-data) talks a little bit about `Rc::clone(&x)` and `x.clone()` (in the last paragraph of that section). Simply put, the former one is just used to distinguish clones that increase the reference count from deep-copy ones.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any difference between these options?

There is a difference when `x` is `None`.

With `let y = Some(Rc::clone(&x.unwrap()));` it will panic, while with `let y = x.clone();` it will assign `None` to `y`.

When `x` is `Some` then there is no difference indeed.

So unless you explicitly want it to panic when `x` is `None`, the second option is recommended on top of being more concise.