# RefMut borrowed from Option does not live long enough (Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>)

Tags: rust, directed-acyclic-graphs, borrow-checker, refcell

First of all, I apologize if this question has been asked before. The only similar problem I could find was this (but it seems different) :

[Cyclic reference does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274049/cyclic-reference-does-not-live-long-enough)

My code is :

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

type NodePointer = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    pub value : i32,
    pub next : NodePointer
}

fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![None; 2];
    let new_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value : 0,
                next : None
            }));
    vector[1] = Some(Rc::clone(&new_node));
    let new_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
                value : 0,
                next : Some(Rc::clone(&new_node))
            }));
    vector[0] = Some(new_node);
    println!("{:?}", vector);

    // the following 3 lines would represent a body of the loop
    let mut a = vector[0].as_ref(); // Option<&Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
    let b = a.take().unwrap().borrow_mut(); // RefMut<Node>
    a = b.next.as_ref(); //ERROR : borrowed value 'b' does not live long enough

    println!("{:?}", vector);
}
```

The code below presents a short excerpt of my complete code. It is a bit weird, but variable 'a' would be used for looping over a vector (more than 2 values in complete code).

**What I am trying to do is to make sure that variable 'a' is replaced with 'next' argument from vector[0] without modifying vector.**

Compiler complains that 'b' does not live long enough, but I don't see why this is the case.

According to my understanding :

- vector[0] is Option<Rc<...>>
- variable 'a' is Option<&Rc<...>>
- a.take() **does not** modify vector[0]
- a.take() instead replaces 'a' with None
- borrow_mut() should give a reference to vector[0], but for some reason it doesn't (?) **<- I think this is the problem here**
- something happened to b, but I don't see what.

**I am also aware that I could make use of Option::take() method instead of take_ref() (and it works in my complete code together with some additional modifications), but I would like to keep vector unmodified in-between 2 println statements**

EDIT :
for information, the following loop body would compile, but it modifies vector...

```
let mut a = vector[0].take(); // Option<&Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
let temp = a.unwrap();
let mut b = temp.borrow_mut(); // RefMut<Node>
a = b.next.take(); //ERROR : borrowed value 'b' does not live long enough
```

Comment: `borrow_mut() should give a reference to vector[0], but for some reason it doesn't` -- actually it's expected to return the guard object that allows you to mutably borrow the contents of `RefCell` without a mutable borrow on the `RefCell` itself.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong (still not 100% confident about the borrow checker), but I think the issue is this:

```rust
    // b borrows from a
    let b = a.take().unwrap().borrow_mut();
    // now, a borrows from b
    // note that the lifetime of `a` doesn't magically change just because you're not using the original value anymore
    // so from the type checker's perspective, a and b borrow from each other at the same time – not allowed
    a = b.next.as_ref();
    
    // btw, if you replace `a =` with `let c =` or even `let a =`, creating a new variable with a new lifetime, it compiles
    // let a = b.next.as_ref();
    // but doesn't work for us since you want to put it in a loop
```

And I think it makes sense. In the first iteration, you get a `Option<&Rc<_>>` by borrowing from `vector`. But if you had a `Option<&Rc<_>>` in the second iteration, where would it be borrowed from? You didn't take it from `vector`, you took it from stuff that only lived during the last iteration – it might be invalid. Or otherwise you would somehow need to ensure that all of the intermediate `RefMut`s somehow lived for the duration of the loop.

I don't think you can borrow something from one iteration to bring it to the next.

Instead, you should take advantage of the reference counting that you already have:

```rust
    let mut next = vector[0].clone();
    while let Some(node) = next {
        next = node.borrow_mut().next.clone();
    }
```

Now, `next` has type `Option<Rc<_>>` – shared ownership instead of a borrow.

Comment: I found out the same as you with `let c`, but my impression was that reassignment of a mutable variable is treated almost the same as the dropping of the previous and the creation of a new variable.

Comment: Aaah,I wasn't aware. I recommend you to add the following link in your answer : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674830/how-to-clone-an-option-of-rc-in-rust
This will complete your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to expand on the answer given by Reinis Mazeiks a bit. I've modified your code slightly to remove some of the non-critical stuff.

```rs
let mut a = vector[0].as_deref();
let b = a.unwrap().borrow();
a = b.next.as_deref();
```

The yields the same error of "`b` does not live long enough." The variable `a` is borrowing from `vector`, and `b` is transitively borrowing from `vector` as well. For instance, the following will compile:

```rs
let b: Ref<'_, Node>;
{
    let a = vector[0].as_deref();
    b = a.unwrap().borrow();
} // a is dropped
// This is okay because b's lifetime is tied to vector
println!("{}", b.value);
```

However, `borrow` returns an owned value, a `Ref<'_, T>`. On the third line in the first code block, the compiler doesn't see us borrowing from `a`, or `vector`, is sees us borrowing from `b`. This is because `Deref` (which is implicitly called when you call `as_ref` in your code), takes an `&self`, so we can only borrow something through `Deref` for at most as long as it lives, and that `Ref` lives only as long as `b`.

Now we run into a pickle here. Let's label some lifetimes and unpack things a bit:

```rs
let mut a = vector[0].as_deref(); // Option<&'a RefCell<Node>>
let b = a.unwrap().borrow(); // Ref<'b, Node>
let temp = b.next.as_deref(); // Option<&'c RefCell<Node>>
a = temp;
```

The second line requires that `'a: 'b` (read `'a` lives at least as long as `'b`). This is because that `Ref` is borrowing from the reference held by `a`, and that reference must be valid for as long as `b` lives. When creating `temp`, we then borrow from `b`, so the lifetime `'b` must satisfy `'b: 'c`, but more importantly `'c` also cannot outlive the variable `b`, since it's borrowing through the owned `Ref` which must be dropped. However the fourth line requires that `'c: 'a` in order to follow the rules of variance and sub-typing. Since we're assigning something that lives for `'c` to something that lives for `'a`, it follows that `'c` must be at least as long as `'a`. Overall this comes full-circle to say that `'a = 'c`. But this is a problem because `'a` and `'c` come from **different values** which are dropped at **different times**, and because `Ref` does not allows its generic arguments to dangle in its drop implementation, our program gets rejected by the drop check.

For fun, I copied the relevant parts of `std`'s `RefCell` implementation, but changed the drop implementation of `BorrowRef` (which `Ref` contains) to the following:

```rs
unsafe impl<#[may_dangle] 'a> Drop for BorrowRef<'a> {
    #[inline]
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // This is UB
        let borrow = self.borrow.get();
        debug_assert!(is_reading(borrow));
        // This is also UB
        self.borrow.set(borrow - 1);
    }
}
```

Using the custom `RefCell` with this modification allows the three problematic lines to compile, validating the theoretical argument above. However, **do not even think about doing this** because the drop implementation uses references which live for `'a`, so **this is undefined behavior**, and hence why your program was rejected.

Comment: In your first code block, if we just add `let` at the beginning of the 3rd line: `let a = b.next.as_deref();`, then it compiles. I'm having a hard time understanding why this makes a difference, since in both cases it should be the same outcome in terms of lifetimes. It compiles even if we use a completely new variable, `let c = ...`, letting `a` live on.

Comment: When you change the third line to be `let a`, then you're no longer assigning to the same variable, meaning that final constraint of `'c: 'a` is no longer required. The type of `a` on the third line would just be `Option<&'c RefCell<Node>>`, which doesn't cause any cyclic constraints which were the root of the issue

Comment: Also, upon rereading my answer I found a couple ill-placed typos and decided to clarify some things, so rereading it now will hopefully make more sense.

Comment: It seems that the solution `'a == 'b == 'c` is acceptable, just not accepted by the current borrow checker. [Here it is](https://godbolt.org/z/951rd7K95) working with nightly rustc.

Comment: There seems to be more going on here with the nightly compiler. If we force `a` to have a non-trivial `Drop` implementation then it [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/oPzzjo3M9) with a similar error to the original. If we just make `a` non-`Copy`, then the drop order it decides on is `a`, then `b`, then `vector`. I honestly don't have a great argument for what's going on here, especially when it comes to `a`'s `Drop` impl affecting everything. If it's fine to drop first with an empty drop impl, why does that change with a non-empty impl? I might be worth asking a compiler team member

Comment: @IanS.
Do you know how to attract attention of compiler team? Or should I just hope that they will notice my question eventually? :p
Answer given by Reinis is enough for my situation, but I am curious what is going on here.